# Unable to filter an array using Azure ADF Filter Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to filter out one value from the array using a Set Variable & Filter activities, but i am not getting the filtered value in the filter activity output. Could you please guide me to make it work as expected?

1.Set Variable activity

[image]

2.Filter Activity

[image]

3.

Output
{
"ItemsCount": 1,
"FilteredItemsCount": 0,
"Value": []
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Var` variable like this: `abc,def` and the expression in the Filter activity should be like this:`@equals(item(),'abc')`.

**Screenshots**:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]